# Pine Script draw horizontal ray starting from first previous day candle (intraday)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I'm really new to pine-script and I'm trying to make a script to draw a horizontal ray line that starts at the first previous day candle to show Previous Day High, Low and Close. I found a similar script for can't get it to work.

```
//@version=4
study("PRIOR DAY LEVELS", overlay=true)

PDH = security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",high)
PDC = security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",close)
PDL = security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",low)

var line l_pdh = na, var line l_pdc = na, var line l_pdl = na

// if barstate.islast
l_pdh := line.new(bar_index-1, PDH, bar_index, PDH, extend=extend.right, color=color.green)
l_pdc := line.new(bar_index-1, PDC, bar_index, PDC, extend=extend.right, color=color.purple)
l_pdl := line.new(bar_index-1, PDL, bar_index, PDL, extend=extend.right, color=color.red)

line.delete(l_pdh[1])
line.delete(l_pdc[1])
line.delete(l_pdl[1])
```

With this script the horizontal ray-line line starts 1 prior candle. I think I have to use xloc.bar_time instead of bar_index but cannot figuere it out.

As always any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT

The answer provided by @vitruvius works well. I'm now trying to add to more lines for PreMarket High/Low.

My new code looks like:

```
//@version=4
study("PRIOR DAY LEVELS", overlay=true)

PDH = security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",high[1])
PDC = security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",close[1])
PDL = security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",low[1])

//Premarket high and low
t = time("1440","0400-0930") // 1440 is the number of minutes in a whole day.
bar_idx_pm = bar_index - valuewhen(t, bar_index, 1)

is_first = na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t
ending_hour = 9
ending_minute = 30

pm_high = float(na)
pm_low = float(na)

if is_first and barstate.isnew and ((hour < ending_hour or hour >= 16) or (hour == ending_hour and minute < ending_minute))
    pm_high := high
    pm_low := low
else 
    pm_high := pm_high[1]
    pm_low := pm_low[1]

if high > pm_high and ((hour < ending_hour or hour >= 1600) or (hour == ending_hour and minute < ending_minute))
    pm_high := high
    
if low < pm_low and ((hour < ending_hour or hour >= 1600) or (hour == ending_hour and minute < ending_minute))
    pm_low := low

// PREMARKET END


is_new_day = change(time("1D"))
bar_idx_prev_day = bar_index - valuewhen(is_new_day, bar_index, 1)
bgcolor(is_new_day ? color.blue : na)

var line l_pdh = na, var line l_pdc = na, var line l_pdl = na, var line l_pmh = na, var line l_pml = na

// if barstate.islast
l_pdh := line.new(bar_index-bar_idx_prev_day, PDH, bar_index, PDH, extend=extend.right, color=color.green)
l_pdc := line.new(bar_index-bar_idx_prev_day, PDC, bar_index, PDC, extend=extend.right, color=color.purple)
l_pdl := line.new(bar_index-bar_idx_prev_day, PDL, bar_index, PDL, extend=extend.right, color=color.red)

l_pmh := line.new(bar_index-bar_idx_pm, pm_high, bar_index, pm_high, extend=extend.right, color=color.blue)
l_pml := line.new(bar_index-bar_idx_pm, pm_low, bar_index, pm_low, extend=extend.right, color=color.orange)

line.delete(l_pdh[1])
line.delete(l_pdc[1])
line.delete(l_pdl[1])
line.delete(l_pmh[1])
line.delete(l_pml[1])
```

This works but I would like to move the PreMarket Horizontal Ray to start at the First PreMarket candle. Currently is at last bar of the pre-market

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [History reference operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator) to get the data from the previous day together with the `security()` function.

Then figure out the bar index of the first bar of the previous day.

```
//@version=4
study("PRIOR DAY LEVELS", overlay=true)

PDH = security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",high[1])
PDC = security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",close[1])
PDL = security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",low[1])

is_new_day = change(time("1D"))
bar_idx_prev_day = bar_index - valuewhen(is_new_day, bar_index, 1)
bgcolor(is_new_day ? color.blue : na)

var line l_pdh = na, var line l_pdc = na, var line l_pdl = na

// if barstate.islast
l_pdh := line.new(bar_index-bar_idx_prev_day, PDH, bar_index, PDH, extend=extend.right, color=color.green)
l_pdc := line.new(bar_index-bar_idx_prev_day, PDC, bar_index, PDC, extend=extend.right, color=color.purple)
l_pdl := line.new(bar_index-bar_idx_prev_day, PDL, bar_index, PDL, extend=extend.right, color=color.red)

line.delete(l_pdh[1])
line.delete(l_pdc[1])
line.delete(l_pdl[1])
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks so much. It works wonderfully. I'm now trying to add 2 more lines for pre-market high/low. What I can't figure out the bar index for the first pre-market candle.

t = time("1440","0400-0930") // 1440 is the number of minutes in a whole day.
bar_idx_pm = bar_index - valuewhen(t, bar_index, 1)

Comment: I eddited my question with the new code. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hello please ask one question per post. So, please ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry about that. Quick question related to this question, Is there a way to make the horizontal ray start at 9:30am the previous day. Currently if I have the extended session on, the lines starts at previous pre-market